# Is it possible to terminate faster a container in local, after a rollout in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rollout

When I am in local, with minikube, I checked that each time I rebuild my app, and roll it out with :

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/api-local -n influx
```

The container lasts 30 sec to be terminated. I have no problem for production matters, but in local dev, I end losing a lot of time waiting, as I can rebuild my app 100 times maybe ( = losing 50 minutes a day ).

Is there some trick to shorten this terminating time ? I understand this would not be part of k8s best practices, but it would make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` in the deployment/pod configuration. Per the [reference docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#pod-v1-core), it is:

> ...Optional duration in seconds the pod needs to terminate gracefully.
>   May be decreased in delete request. Value must be non-negative
>   integer. The value zero indicates delete immediately. If this value is
>   nil, the default grace period will be used instead. The grace period
>   is the duration in seconds after the processes running in the pod are
>   sent a termination signal and the time when the processes are forcibly
>   halted with a kill signal. Set this value longer than the expected
>   cleanup time for your process. Defaults to 30 seconds.

Example:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    ...
  template:
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      containers:
      ...
```

Also, from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods):

> The kubectl delete command supports the --grace-period=
>   option which allows a user to override the default and specify their
>   own value. The value 0 force deletes the Pod. You must specify an
>   additional flag --force along with --grace-period=0 in order to
>   perform force deletions.

Example (specify the namespace, if needed):

```
kubectl delete pod <pod-name> --now
```

...or

```
kubectl delete pod <pod-name> --grace-period=0 --force
```